# Returning const with fragment to

Tags: reactjs, syntax

I have a `const` `requiredText` with some HTML. Returning `requiredText` with `React.Fragment`s to my Storybook story generates no output for reason.

If I define `requiredText` as below without fragments, it works fine:

```
const requiredText = (
  <div>
    <p>This isn't rendering</p>
    <p>and I'm not sure why</p>
  </div>
);
```

Don't think I have the syntax right. How do I define the below the below `const`? Does it need to be a function?

```js
const requiredText = () => (
  <>
    <p>This isn't rendering</p>
    <p>the syntax must be wrong</p>
  </>
);

const BannerStory = () => {
  return <Banner header={requiredText} />;
};

class Banner extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <SomeComponent anotherprop={this.props.header} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: "_If I define requiredText as below without fragments, it works fine:_" - No, it won't work fine. Adjacent JSX tags must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

Comment: @kinduser sorry yes edited out the wrapper div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing requiredText, so you're passing in a reference to the function, not it's return value.

do:

```
const BannerStory = () => {
  return <Banner header={requiredText()} />;
};
```

in order to "inject" the return value of requiredText

so if you do

```
console.log( requiredText )
```

you get:

```
Object {key: null, ref: null, props: Object, _owner: null, _store: Object}
key: null
ref: null
props: Object
children: Array[2] <-- contains the text in requiredText
0: Object
type: "p"
key: null
ref: null
props: Object
children: "This isn't rendering"
_owner: null
_store: Object
1: Object
_owner: null
_store: Object
```

whereas executing a function captures the return value

Answer (score 1):

In the following code block:

```
const BannerStory = () => {
  return <Banner header={requiredText} />;
};
```

> You are passing a **function**, not the **component** itself. Execute it before passing down the children.

```
const BannerStory = () => {
  return <Banner header={requiredText()} />;
};
```

If the fragment syntax `<>` does not work for you, check your webpack settings. You could also try `React.Fragment` instead, which works in the same way as `<>`.

```
const requiredText = (
  <React.Fragment>
    <p>This isn't rendering</p>
    <p>and I'm not sure why</p>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll award based on timestamp 